# Sonar is not getting started giving error of heapSize

Tags: sonarqube, sonar-runner

I am using Sonar for my code review in project, according to the process as soon as I start "start-sonar.bat" file it is giving error like 
[image]
I think the problem is due to the Heap overflow, but i don't know how to change or get through it

Help me to rectify it.

Comment: Can you check that you don't have anything in the "data/" folder?

Comment: I see no error here, please check the server's logs for hints.

Comment: Yes I have some data in database in this hierarchy
D:\sonarqube-4.5.2\data\es\sonarqube\nodes\0\_state